# How to force SQL query counting max/min/avg to working correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem to write correct sql query which should select min/max/avg of duration in days between two dates by country and site for the trial.

### My query:

```
SELECT v.country as country, v.site as site,
  COUNT(*) as N --,
  --MAX(list of durations in days between discovered date to repored date on each violation by country and site) as "Maximum",
  --MIN(list of durations in days between discovered date to repored date on each violation by country and site) as "Minimum",
  --AVG(list of durations in days between discovered date to repored date on each violation by country and site) as "Mean"
FROM violations v
WHERE v.trial_id = 3
GROUP BY ROLLUP (v.country, v.site)
```

Here is my [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46249/6/0) with data structure and query needed to improve commented lines.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Oracle, dates are stored as offsets, so you can simply subtract 1 date from the other. See [Date arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3839) for more information.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5651/1/0)

```
SELECT v.country as country, v.site as site,
  COUNT(*) as N,
  MAX(reporded_date - discovered_date) as "Maximum",
  MIN(reporded_date - discovered_date) as "Minimum",
  AVG(reporded_date - discovered_date) as "Mean"
FROM violations v
WHERE v.trial_id = 3
GROUP BY ROLLUP (v.country, v.site)
```

Note that the test-data you supplied was always 1 day apart, so I've updated that (for Germany) in my fiddle as well.

Comment: what in situation where date is null?

Comment: @Roman Well, what would you want to happen? Would you want to use the current date in it's place? Or would you want it to evaluate the calculation to null? Can `discovered_date` be null? etc., etc. However, broadly you would use `NVL` and `COALESCE` to deal with null values, as you would in any other query.

Comment: Which date? And what do you want to happen when it is null? Read the documentation for [COALESCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm) and [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#i91798), and [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm#i1033392).

Comment: both can be empty, when is empty i suggest to return 0

Comment: @Roman Returning 0 would utterly destroy your averages (e.g. if one if your `discovered_date`s was null, then your MAX and AVG would likely return a value in the millions). With respect, I think you need to read the documentation, and have a play around to see what is sensible for *your* application. One hint though - don't forget you can use the current date in place of a null value - that is often appropriate.

Comment: you're right, i think when null/empty date appears then such a violation should not be taken into account

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is put the difference between the reported and discovered dates within the aggregate functions:

```
SELECT v.country as country, v.site as site,
  COUNT(*) as N,
  MAX(reported_date-discovered_date) as "Maximum",
  MIN(reported_date-discovered_date) as "Minimum",
  AVG(reported_date-discovered_date) as "Mean"
FROM violations v
WHERE v.trial_id = 3
GROUP BY ROLLUP (v.country, v.site)
```

The SQLFiddle data you have provided won't actually show any difference, so [here is an updated version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00e4e/1).